# implement apply and t.test functions same time

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I am using R, I have a couple conditions with three replicates in each and I want to apply t.test to each of the elements in the conditions (the rows). For this I am willing to use apply function to the dataset (143,554 rows) containing all the info and specifying to retrieve the pval obtained by the t.test.

The columns 4,6,8 are the replicates for the first condition (main element of apply), the colums 10,12,14 are the elements of the second condition (example data at the end). And I thought that something like this could do the work:

`t.test.10x = apply( MT.10x[,c(4,6,8)], 1, function(x) t.test(x, MT.10x[,c(10,12,14)])$p.value)`

However this syntax is wrong because providing the whole table for the second condition in t.test will not go row by row, instead this approach will compare all the rows in 10,12,14 to each row in 4,6,8.

I don't want to use for loop but if it is absolutely required... well..

Thank you!!

Dataset example:

```
Chr Start End wt1_R wt1_T wt2_R wt2_T wt3_R wt3_T ko1_R ko1_T ko2_R ko2_T ko3_R ko3_T
chr1 3060417 3060419 0.0698 43 0.25 28 0.172 29 0.188 32 0.156 45 0.119 42
chr1 3060431 3060433 0.786 28 0.818 22 0.526 19 0.895 19 0.833 36 0.784 37
chr1 3168805 3168807 0.688 16 1 19 0.769 13 0.929 14 0.933 15 0.9 10
chr1 3228992 3228994 0.7 10 1 11 0.786 14 1 14 0.938 16 0.923 13
chr1 3233065 3233067 0.857 14 0.917 12 1 17 0.846 13 0.857 21 0.952 21
chr1 3265234 3265236 0.84 25 0.727 11 0.909 22 0.968 31 0.895 19 0.905 21
chr1 3265322 3265324 0.111 27 0.25 28 0.55 20 0.385 13 0.467 15 0.462 13
chr1 3265345 3265347 0.806 31 0.857 35 0.733 30 0.9 30 0.8 25 1 17
chr1 3265357 3265359 1 30 0.759 29 0.758 33 0.867 30 0.903 31 1 18
chr1 3265486 3265488 1 15 0.545 22 1 13 0.8 10 0.917 12 1 24
chr1 3265512 3265514 0.857 28 0.75 20 0.583 24 0.714 21 0.882 17 0.839 31
chr1 3265540 3265542 0.757 37 0.966 29 0.969 32 0.774 31 0.955 22 0.971 34
chr1 3265771 3265773 0.741 27 0.864 22 0.963 27 1 20 0.864 22 0.962 26
chr1 3265776 3265778 1 20 1 21 1 26 0.722 18 1 24 0.852 27
chr1 3265803 3265805 0.611 18 0.96 25 1 17 1 18 0.895 19 0.828 29
chr1 3760225 3760227 0.278 36 0.0741 27 0.417 24 0.158 19 0.4 40 0.136 22
chr1 3760285 3760287 0.851 47 0.711 38 0.867 15 0.81 21 0.914 35 0.893 28
chr1 3761299 3761301 0.786 14 0.885 26 1 11 0.929 14 0.771 35 0.75 24
chr1 3761414 3761416 0.706 17 1 17 0.545 22 0.857 14 0.818 11 0.8 15
chr1 3838606 3838608 0.806 31 0.692 13 0.611 18 1 11 1 23 1 11
chr1 3838611 3838613 0.767 30 1 13 0.947 19 0.818 11 1 20 1 11
chr1 4182108 4182110 0.231 13 0.5 14 0.143 21 0.0667 15 0.235 17 0.353 17
chr1 4547434 4547436 0.9 10 1 13 1 17 1 14 0.909 11 0.909 11
chr1 4547456 4547458 1 18 1 10 0.895 19 0.833 12 1 12 1 12
chr1 4547496 4547498 0.812 16 0.917 12 0.75 16 0.923 13 0.818 11 0.9 10
chr1 4547509 4547511 1 14 1 12 1 15 0.9 10 0.833 12 1 11
chr1 4547512 4547514 0.923 13 1 12 1 14 0.909 11 0.833 12 0.909 11
chr1 4765732 4765734 0 11 0 12 0 11 0 13 0 13 0.1 10
chr1 5185343 5185345 0.818 22 0.909 22 0.963 27 1 15 0.923 13 1 16
chr1 5185567 5185569 0.885 52 0.781 32 0.984 63 1 37 0.844 45 1 29
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `mapply`:

```
mapply(function(x,y)
          t.test(x,y)$p.value,
          MT.10x[,c(4,6,8)], MT.10x[,c(10,12,14)])

##    wt1_R     wt2_R     wt3_R 
##  0.4790554 0.8289961 0.5204527
```

Comment: I think that is wrong...
mapply apply the t.test to the columns, so this compare the 30 elements of the column 4 to the  30 elements of the column 10 and so on (6-12 and 8-14). This is the reason why this only obtain three values instead of the  thirty expected